# All finite sums bounded implies countable

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X$ be a set of positive real numbers, and let $S$ be the set of all finite sums of members of $X$. Suppose that $S$ is bounded. Prove that $X$ is countable.

Not much idea on how to start here. A contrapositive would require proving that if $X$ is uncountable, then $S$ is unbounded. A big ask, it seems.

Comment: Okay, it's pretty much the same. Thanks!